# Jquery - How do I fade one class to another

Tags: jquery, fade

I'm new to jquery and I've got myself stuck on something, how do I add a fade to a piece of script? I have a fixed header and want the class to fade to another class after I scroll 60px, I've managed to stitch this together so far...

I thought the .fadeIn bit would work, but, it doesn't :)

Any help would be muchly appreciated! Thanks.

```
<script>
var fixed = false;


$(document).scroll(function() {
if( $(this).scrollTop() > 60 ) {
    if( !fixed ) {
        fixed = true;
        $('.header').css({background:'#242323'}).fadeIn('fast');
        $('.header').css("border-bottom-color", "#242323").fadeIn('fast');
    }
} else {
    if( fixed ) {
        fixed = false;
        $('.header').css({background:'none'}).fadeIn('fast');
        $('.header').css("border-bottom-color", "#fff").fadeIn('fast');
    }
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for fade in to work you need to have your element not displayed. So by not displaying it initially and then fading in and out you will achieve the effect you are looking for.

**CSS**
/*This css can be accommodated within js if desired. For this example, since the layout is not known and also for clarity, it has been separated.*/
    .header{
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        position:fixed;
        display:none;
        color:white;
    }

**JS**

```
var fixed = false;

$(document).scroll(function() {
if( $(this).scrollTop() > 60 ) {
    if( !fixed ) {
        fixed = true;
        $('.header').css({background:'#242323',
                          'border-bottom':'1px solid #242323'}).fadeIn('fast');
    }
} else {
    if( fixed ) {
        fixed = false;
        $('.header').fadeOut('fast');
    }
}
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">the header</div>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus....</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vjk9a/